# Why is anchor tag not clickable outside of parent

Tags: css

I am working on a similar carousel and encountered the same problem that this snippet has. The anchor tag, which is positioned above a pseudo element for the style, is not clickable outside of the carousel. Why is that?

I wouldn't expect this behaviour because they are positioned `absolutely`.

```css
@keyframes tonext {
  75% {
    left: 0;
  }
  95% {
    left: 100%;
  }
  98% {
    left: 100%;
  }
  99% {
    left: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes tostart {
  75% {
    left: 0;
  }
  95% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  98% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  99% {
    left: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes snap {
  96% {
    scroll-snap-align: center;
  }
  97% {
    scroll-snap-align: none;
  }
  99% {
    scroll-snap-align: none;
  }
  100% {
    scroll-snap-align: center;
  }
}

body {
  max-width: 37.5rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 1.25rem;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  scrollbar-color: transparent transparent; /* thumb and track color */
  scrollbar-width: 0px;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
}

* {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}

ol, li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.carousel {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 75%;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 10px #0003);
  perspective: 100px;
}

.carousel__viewport {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  counter-reset: item;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}

.carousel__slide {
  position: relative;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f99;
  counter-increment: item;
}

.carousel__slide:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #99f;
}

.carousel__slide:before {
  content: counter(item);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%,-40%,70px);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.carousel__snapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
}

@media (hover: hover) {
  .carousel__snapper {
    animation-name: tonext, snap;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  }

  .carousel__slide:last-child .carousel__snapper {
    animation-name: tostart, snap;
  }
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
  .carousel__snapper {
    animation-name: none;
  }
}

.carousel:hover .carousel__snapper,
.carousel:focus-within .carousel__snapper {
  animation-name: none;
}

.carousel__navigation {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.carousel__navigation-list,
.carousel__navigation-item {
  display: inline-block;
}

.carousel__navigation-button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  background-color: #333;
  background-clip: content-box;
  border: 0.25rem solid transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: transform 0.1s;
}

.carousel::before,
.carousel::after,
.carousel__prev,
.carousel__next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 37.5%;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 0;
  outline: 0;
}

.carousel::before,
.carousel__prev {
  left: -1rem;
}

.carousel::after,
.carousel__next {
  right: -1rem;
}

.carousel::before,
.carousel::after {
  content: '';
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #333;
  background-size: 1.5rem 1.5rem;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  line-height: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.carousel::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 100 100' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpolygon points='0,50 80,100 80,0' fill='%23fff'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.carousel::after {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 100 100' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpolygon points='100,50 20,100 20,0' fill='%23fff'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

```html
<h1>CSS-only Carousel</h1>

<p>This carousel is created with HTML and CSS only.</p>

<section class="carousel" aria-label="Gallery">
  <ol class="carousel__viewport">
    <li id="carousel__slide1"
        tabindex="0"
        class="carousel__slide">
      <div class="carousel__snapper">
        <a href="#carousel__slide4"
           class="carousel__prev">Go to last slide</a>
        <a href="#carousel__slide2"
           class="carousel__next">Go to next slide</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id="carousel__slide2"
        tabindex="0"
        class="carousel__slide">
      <div class="carousel__snapper"></div>
      <a href="#carousel__slide1"
         class="carousel__prev">Go to previous slide</a>
      <a href="#carousel__slide3"
         class="carousel__next">Go to next slide</a>
    </li>
    <li id="carousel__slide3"
        tabindex="0"
        class="carousel__slide">
      <div class="carousel__snapper"></div>
      <a href="#carousel__slide2"
         class="carousel__prev">Go to previous slide</a>
      <a href="#carousel__slide4"
         class="carousel__next">Go to next slide</a>
    </li>
    <li id="carousel__slide4"
        tabindex="0"
        class="carousel__slide">
      <div class="carousel__snapper"></div>
      <a href="#carousel__slide3"
         class="carousel__prev">Go to previous slide</a>
      <a href="#carousel__slide1"
         class="carousel__next">Go to first slide</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <aside class="carousel__navigation">
    <ol class="carousel__navigation-list">
      <li class="carousel__navigation-item">
        <a href="#carousel__slide1"
           class="carousel__navigation-button">Go to slide 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="carousel__navigation-item">
        <a href="#carousel__slide2"
           class="carousel__navigation-button">Go to slide 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="carousel__navigation-item">
        <a href="#carousel__slide3"
           class="carousel__navigation-button">Go to slide 3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="carousel__navigation-item">
        <a href="#carousel__slide4"
           class="carousel__navigation-button">Go to slide 4</a>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </aside>
</section>
```

Source: https://codepen.io/Schepp/pen/WNbQByE

Comment: All the 6 anchor tags work pretty fine with me. Can you specify which one of them is not working?

Comment: I often use `display: block;` for positioned `a` tags. Try giving `.carousel__prev, .carousel__next` both `display: block;`. The pseudo-elements don't need it AFAIK.

Comment: @LeoRamadani They are working, but you'll notice the arrows are not clickable when the mouse is outside the colored rectable below.

Comment: It's because `.carousel__viewport` has `overflow-x: scroll;`, which limits the parts of the LI that get shown, to the width of that viewport. Your circles with the triangles are visible, because those are not inside the viewport element to begin with - but _clicking_ them does nothing whatsoever t begin with, what you are clicking on are the links inside the LI, which you simply visually overlay onto those icons - and those links get cut off.